# Python-lxml wrap only part of tag's content into a further tag

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I'm an almost-complete beginner, and I'm trying to extract Twitter data from JSON into a pseudo-XML file using lxml.

The final structure that I need to have is as follows:

```
<corpus>
   <text id="NNN" source="NNN">
      text of the message
   </text>
</corpus>
```

I have succeded in obtaining the above, but when the text contains hashtags I need to wrap each hashtag inside a new tag, such as follow:

```
<corpus>
   <text id="NNN" source="NNNN">
      text of the message with <exhashtag original="#hashtag">hashtag</exhashtag>
   </text>
</corpus>
```

I.e. each hashtag has to be stripped of the hash character, and included inside of a custom `<exhashtag>` tag that contains its original version.

So far, this is what I've written - where `text_field` is the final pseudo-XML structure for the tag `<text>`, and `json_text` is the text extracted from the json:

```
if re.search(u'(?:\#+[\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_]+)', json_text) is not None:
   alltags = re.findall(u'(?:\#+[\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_]+)', json_text)
      for i in alltags:
         if i is not None:
            json_text_hashtags = i
            json_text_nohashtags = re.sub(u'(?:\#+([\w_]+[\w\'_\-]*[\w_])+)', u'\g<1>', i)
            exhashtag = etree.SubElement(text_field, "exhashtag", original=json_text_hashtags)
            exhashtag.text = json_text_nohashtags
            json_textstring_hash = text_field.insert(2,exhashtag)
```

but the result looks as follows:

```
<corpus>
   <text id="NNN" source="NNNN">
      text of message with #hashtag <exhashtag orginal="#hashtag">hashtag</exhashtag>
   </text>
</corpus>
```

Any suggestion as to how correctly include the `exhashtag` for each hashtag in the text, in the correct place?
Many thanks in advance, I hope I have included all the info needed.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `text_field.insert`, I would just replace `text_field.text`

```
text_field.text = text_field.text.replace(
    json_text_hashtags,
    etree.tostring(exhashtag, encoding=str)
)
```

By default, `etree.tostring` serializes element to *bytes* object. Use `str` (or `unicode` in Python 2) function as encoding to get string.